# console on port 5554 and adb on port 5555 error

Tags: android, android-studio

I am having an error in android studio while running my first app "Hi World".
I am in learning process and has just started learning android development.
Kindly help, I shall be very thankful to you.
This is the error code:
C:\Android\sdk1\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd

Nexus_5_API_23

Hax is enabled

Hax ram_size 0x40000000

HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.

adb_server_notify: Failed to establish connection to ADB server

console on port 5554, ADB on port 5555

Answer (score 0):

The `adb` client should start or look for servers running on `port 5037`. This is setup by default so `adb kill-server` & `adb start-server` should fix the issue. The device or emulator should have a listening adb daemon running as a background process on `port 5554` and upwards which is correct from what you posted above.